# Android studio la app se crashea

Tags: java, android

Estoy programando en *Android Studio* con java. Alguien me pudiera ayudar. Presiono mi botón y sí suma, pero al presionar por segunda vez, la app siempre se sale. Es un contador pero de 0.5 en 0.5. No sé si tenga que ver por mis variables o qué.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button boton;
    TextView contador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boton = findViewById(R.id.boton);
        contador = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contadorT);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double cont = Integer.valueOf(contador.getText().toString());
                double a = 0.5;
                double resultado = cont + a;
                contador.setText(""+resultado);
            }
        });
```

Comment: No se porqué te da la excepción. Tal vez si pusieras el error concreto que te da, podría afinar más mi respuesta. Otra cosa: Si el TextView va a contener números con decimales, si al obtener el valor actual lo conviertes a Integer, perderás la parte decimal. Esto te pasa cuando das valor a `cont`.

Comment: Es super importante agregar el error descrito en el LogCAT!

Comment: Me sale este error: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.contador, PID: 11872
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"

Answer (score 1):

Cambia tu Integer.valueOf por Double.valueOf el problema se debe a que los enteros no deben tener punto decimal.

O quitaría más bien el contador (la parte del double) de la presentación en pantalla. ejemplo:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button boton;
TextView contador;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boton = findViewById(R.id.boton);
    contador = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contadorT);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private double cont = 0.5;
        private DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cont += 0.5;
            contador.setText(nf.format(cont));
        }
    });
```

La parte de new View.OnClickListener ya ameritaría para generar una clase mínimo interna, o generar un ContadorListener que implemente la interfaz View.OnClickListener.